# Postgres lo_import fails with could not open server file "\\ipaddress\test.pdf": No such file or directory

Tags: linux, postgresql, server, window, plpgsql

I have created PostgreSQL function which takes file path as input and returns base 64 encoded file content. The function works as expected on my local but when i execute it on server it gives error **no such file or directory.**

The PostgreSQL server is installed on Linux server and the file is present on windows server. I am executing the select function(ipaddress\file-path\filename) by connecting to PostgreSQL from windows server.

```
create or replace function doc_import(filename text)
  returns character varying
  volatile
  language plpgsql as
$f$
    declare
        content bytea;
        loid oid;
        lfd integer;
        lsize integer;
    begin
        loid := lo_import(filename);
        lfd := lo_open(loid,262144);
        lsize := lo_lseek(lfd,0,2);
        perform lo_lseek(lfd,0,0);
        content := loread(lfd,lsize);
        perform lo_close(lfd);
        perform lo_unlink(loid);
 
         RETURN encode(content, 'base64');
    end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lo_import` is a database server function and can only read files from the database server. There is no way that you can read a client file in PL/pgSQL code.